# Django admin add_view/ change_view for inline

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin we can override the add_view and change_view functions from the ModelAdmin class like this..

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        self.readonly_fields = (...)
        //other code
        return super(ProductAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url='', extra_context=None)
    inlines = [SubProdInLine,]
```

It's similar as above for change_view as well.

However, this is not the case for the Inline model admin. Is there anyway we can replicate the same for inlines like below? Note, the below code doesn't work. I just want to be able to do something like it.

```
class SubProdInLine(admin.TabularInLine)
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        self.readonly_fields = (...)
        //other code
        return super(SubProdInLine, self).add_view(request, form_url='', extra_context=None)
```

Basically, I want to be able to change the readonly_fields in the add_view.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify `readonly_fields` in the `add_view` method - it may affect other requests.

Instead you can override [`get_readonlyfields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields). If the object is `None`, that indicates that you are adding a new object.

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def get_readonly_fields(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            # We are adding an object
            return ('field1', 'field2',)
        else:
            return self.readonly_fields
```

You can then overrride `get_readonly_fields` for your inline class as well.

```
class SubProdAdmin(admin.TabularInLine)
    def get_readonly_fields(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            # We are adding an object
            return ('field1', 'field2',)
        else:
            return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: Erm the problem is that obj is an instance of Product and not of SubProd :-/ Means in the Product change_view, I want to be able to change the readonly_fields of the inlines. Like when I'm adding a SubProd instance to the Product I should be able to change the readonly_fields for it..

Comment: If `obj` is a `Product` in `SubProdAdmin.get_readonly_fields`, then you'll need to dig deeper into the internals. I'm afraid I don't know an easy way to do it.

Comment: Yep your right, I'm going to have to add some JS to get my work done.. I haven't worked much with JS and was hoping Django admin had some functionality to help me.. Thanks though..